# Activity not getting updated after back button pressed when recycler view is implemented

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-adapter, android-recyclerview, back-stack

Activity not getting updating after back button pressed when recycler view is implemented. from A(onClickListener implemented from Adapter)->B(changes database and goes to A upon back button is pressed).

Problem is A is not getting updated after changing values in SQLite database.

May be because am implementing onclick listener in adapter ?

Adapter for A :

public MovieViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

```
        imageView =(ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);


        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = new Intent(context,DetailsActivity.class);

                i.putExtra("fromFavorite",true);
                i.putExtra("movie_id",ids.get(getLayoutPosition()));

                context.startActivity(i);


            }
        });
```

Activity Class:

public class FavoritesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    setValues();


}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    setValues();


}

void setValues() {


}
```

}

Comment: add your activity A code where you load data. Try to load data in onResume() and not in onCreate()

Answer (score 1):

Either reload your data in `onResume`/`onActivityResult` or create a `ContentObserver` that listens to changes in the database.

Answer (score 0):

YOu should load the data in `OnResume()`

**See here..**

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html